# Disabled audio on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, audio

I want to play .wav sound in my application. I know how to do it. For example with a SoundPlayer class:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = @"C:\path\sample.wav";
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

At home I have multiple Applications which can play sounds. However at job, I can't do it. Normally the computer can make sounds (youtube, Windows Media Player, etc.).

I investigated that my application does not appear in Volume Mixer.

Comment: It will appear only when playing something. Better prepare your app to support a "muted" state.

Comment: @Gusman But.. When it needs to have sound? Let say for a blind person.

Comment: Again, prepare it to allow to be muted, just add a setting to mute it and by default set it unmuted, then whenever you need it to be muted activate the option.

Comment: Gusman, I checked it and you are right. The application in volume mixer appear only if is playing something.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was faulty wav file. I converted it to mp3 and then back to wav and now it works.